# Updating database which has a job_id equivalent to Man

Tags: sqlplus

```
SQL> UPDATE COPY_EMPLOYEES
2  SET SALARY=
3  (SELECT SALARY
4  FROM EMPLOYEES
5  WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 142)
6  WHERE JOB_ID='MAN';
```

I have this code 
but the problem i can't update it because all of my job id is equal to MK_MAN and SK_MAN how can I update the row which has a job_id equivalent to 'MAN'

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
WHERE JOB_ID = 'MAN'
```

with

```
WHERE JOB_ID LIKE '%MAN'
```